# ¿Cómo declarar métodos en Java?

Tags: java, constructor

Tengo la necesidad de crear una clase llamada Consorcio, con tres empresas (Empresa A, B, C) que me permita hacer el siguiente cálculo:

El consorcio necesita conocer cuáles son sus gastos por consumo telefónico; adicionalmente, requiere calcular el monto de dinero que debe pagar por impuestos telefónicos. En el momento de conformar el consorcio, las empresas A, B y C se pusieron de acuerdo respecto al manejo de impuestos mensuales asociados al consumo telefónico. Las tarifas se muestran a continuación: Empresa A: $1 por cada llamada más el 4% del total de costo de llamadas Empresa B: $0.01 por cada minuto más 3$ por cada llamada Empresa C: 5% sobre el total de costos por llamadas

He hecho esto, pero aún asi no puedo calcular los montos y devolver el total:

```
public class Consorcio {

    private int numeroLlamadas;
    private int numeroMinutos;
    private double costoLlamadas;    
    private int numeroMinutosCelular;
    private double facturaConsorcio;
    private double totalImpuestos;

    public void inicializar( )
    {

        numeroLlamadas = 0;
        numeroMinutos = 0;
        costoLlamadas = 0;
        numeroMinutosCelular = 0;
        totalImpuestos = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Reinicia la línea telefónica, dejando todos sus valores en cero.
     */
    public void reiniciar( )
    {
        numeroLlamadas = 0;
        numeroMinutos = 0;
        numeroMinutosCelular = 0;
        costoLlamadas = 0;
        totalImpuestos = 0;
    }


    public double darCostoLlamadas( )
    {
        return costoLlamadas;
    }

    public double darTotalFacturaConsorcio ()
    {
        return facturaConsorcio;
    }

    public double darTotalImpuestos ()
    {
        return totalImpuestos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, no está claro lo que estás preguntando, ¿quieres saber cómo se declaran métodos? Ya lo hiciste en tu ejemplo. ¿Quieres saber cómo se hacen cálculos? ¿Tienes otro código? ¿Una clase Empresa? ¿Has intentado algo y tienes un problema en específico?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Ummm no es claro lo que planteas. Pero, viendo el código, me parece que estás lejos de una solución óptima. La clase `Consorcio` debería tener un constructor al que le puedas pasar un array de objetos del tipo `Empresa`, en este caso le pasarías las tres empresas que dices (con todos sus datos dentro, claro... Nombre, Lugar, Etc). Y si es un `Consorcio` de 50 empresas pues no pasa nada, le pasas un array con las 50 empresas... y así por el estilo. Es una vía de solución entre otras posibles. Por supuesto, te faltaría tener una clase llamada `Empresa`.

Answer (score 1):

Un poco complicado entender lo que necesitas, pero bueno haber si te ayuda esto:

Lo primero que necesitas es declarar una clase que tenga método main y después crear 3 objetos simulando las empresas:

```
public class Calcula {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Consorcio empresaA= new Consorcio();
    Consorcio empresaB= new Consorcio();
    Consorcio empresaC= new Consorcio();

    System.out.println(emprseaA.darCostoLlamadas( ));
    System.out.println(emprseaB.darCostoLlamadas( ));
    System.out.println(emprseaC.darCostoLlamadas( ));

    //mas operaciones

}
}
```

También recuerda generar tus setter/getter un tu clase Consorcio

Saludos